# Difficulty to Understand one Mathematics Formula

Tags: java, excel, discrete-mathematics

I have a mathematical formula and had a hard time to understand this and converted in to Java code.

[Attached Image is the formula I have to solve]

[image]

I have written some code and it is not helping much. In the formula I have value for C and P and need to find N.

Below is the code I have used

```
public static Double sigmaSum(int c, int n, Double p){
    Double sum = 0.00;
    for(int i=0; i<c; i++){
    for(int j=i; j<n;j++){
    sum += ((Math.pow(p, j)) * (Math.pow((1-p), (n-j))));
   }
```

I have a corresponding excel formula but I don't know how to convert it into java.

```
Option Explicit
Dim intLTPD, intCL, intC, intCalcF, intK, intComboNum, intComboDen1, intI, intJ, intComboDen2, intCombo, intL As Integer
Dim lngSampleSize As Long

Sub macBinSampPlan()
'
intLTPD = (Range("B1") / 100)
intCL = Range("B2") / 100
'intC = Int(Range("B3"))
Cells.Range("A6").Select

intCombo = 0
intCalcF = 0
intI = 0
intJ = 0

For intC = 0 To 10
    For intI = 1 To 10000
        For intJ = 0 To intC
            If intI >= intJ Then
                intCombo = Application.WorksheetFunction.Combin(intI, intJ)
                intCalcF = intCalcF + (intCombo * (Application.WorksheetFunction.Power(intLTPD, intJ)) * (Application.WorksheetFunction.Power((1 - intLTPD), (intI - intJ))))
            Else
                Exit For
            End If
        Next intJ
        If (intCalcF - (1 - intCL)) / intCalcF <= intLTPD Then
            lngSampleSize = intI
            Exit For
        Else
            intCombo = 0
            intCalcF = 0
        End If
    Next intI
    ActiveCell = intC
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell = lngSampleSize + 1
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, -1).Range("A1").Select
Next intC

End Sub
```

I am working on this around a week and not able to get it resolved.It should be a great help if some body can solve this. Thanks in advance.

Vivek

Comment: It is not clear what you want. Your Java module code takes `c`, 
`n` and `p` but returns nothing. With your Excel VBA code it is totally unclear what the different variables shall be. Maybe `intJ` shall be `i`, so `intC` shall be `c` (10). The `intI` is `n` looping from 1 to 10000, but why? The `intLTPD` (`B1`) may shall be `p`. So why not name the variables in a meaningful manner according to the formula? And what is `intCL` (`B2`), how is it related to `intCalcF`, which is the result of the given formula? And the VBA code writes 10 lines of results. What exactly shall the java code do?

Comment: So please edit your question and provide more informations if you want get answers. Btw.: The term `n choose i` in your formula is [Binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient). It is what Excel's [COMBIN](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COMBIN-function-12a3f276-0a21-423a-8de6-06990aaf638a) calculates.

Comment: Btw.: [BINOM.DIST](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/BINOM-DIST-function-c5ae37b6-f39c-4be2-94c2-509a1480770c) - [Java](http://lacinato.com/cm/software/othersoft/binomdist)

Comment: Excel also has `=BINOM.DIST(c,n,p,TRUE)`. From VBA you could call `Application.WorksheetFunction.Binom_Dist(c,n,p,TRUE)`.

Answer (score 0):

The way your implement your binomial seems to be wrong. According to your formula, the code should rather be:

```
public static Double sigmaSum(int c, int n, Double p){
    Double sum = 0.00;
    for(int i=0; i<c; i++){
    sum += ((CombinatoricsUtils.binomialCoefficientDouble(n,i)) * (Math.pow(p, i)) * (Math.pow((1-p), (n-i))));
   }
}
```

I have not tested the code yet.